# Unable to connect wahoo hr device using Polar BLE SDK

Tags: android

I am facing an issue in Samsung Galaxy Tab A8, Android 11. Trying to connect Wahoo HR device using polar ble sdk. There is inconsistency in device connection. Sometimes it connect, sometimes it taking long time but not connecting.

There is also a similar bug in official github repository issue:
https://github.com/polarofficial/polar-ble-sdk/issues/266

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

We are using the latest version and found the issue but in previous version, it was working properly.

An issue is filed at- https://github.com/polarofficial/polar-ble-sdk/issues/270